# Why is my char * returning a different value?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, buffer

I have a function that looks like this:

```
char *function1(){

//SOME CODE HERE

char result[16];
char *ptr = result;
return ptr;
}
```

So what this does is compute some value (128 bit), store it in the char buffer and then return a pointer to the buffer. 
I print out the buffer within `function1` using this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    printf("%02X ", result[i]);
printf("\n");
```

**result** is a 128 bit value and is printed out.

Now in another function I have following code

```
char *ptr_to_result = function1();
```

I print it using this bit of code again:

```
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    printf("%02X ", ptr_to_result[i]);
printf("\n");
```

**result2** is the 128 bit value this prints out.

For some reason **result** != **result2** and I can't figure out why.

Comment: C does not support _methods_! There is no 128 bit value, `char` has implementation defined signed-ness. And **please** think why `result` is called a **local** variable! Your code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Note that returning a pointer to local storage (`result` in `method1()`) leads to undefined behaviour.  The compiler may arrange for that memory to be reused by other local variables in other functions, and the value in it will be destroyed over time — even if not immediately.

Comment: Ah I see, that's probably it, how do I get around that? Dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: @Django, that's one way. Another way would be pass an array to `function1` and let `function1` fill it with the appropriate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer `result` will vanish on returning from function `function1()`, and accessing the vanished buffer (via returned pointer) invokes *undefined behavior*.

Changing `char result[16];` to `static char result[16];` will prevent `result` from vanishing and should make it work unless you use the function in multi-thread nor interrupt handler. (This change will make the function not reentrant)

Comment: Thank you, and a valuable reminder about the workings of the C stack.

Answer (score 0):

every time you enter a function body, system reserves from the stack a defined amount of memory equal to the size of locally declared variables. when it return it free that memory like a push & pop. so, locally declared variables vanishes, and the stack is reused by other functions that reclaims an amount of space from the stack for its locally declared variables. the pointer for a locally declared variable can not be reused outside the function when it return, because the stack is now owned by an other function, or not yet allocated.